# how can i use quotes in windows console command arguments?

Tags: cmd

i was wondering how i can use quotes in the argument of a console command.
For example: i would like to open opera with the url `www.google.de/?search="hello+world"` but when i use the command `C:\...\Opera\launcher.exe www.google.de/?search="hello+world"` it opens the link without the qoutes.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 64-bit

Shortcut to open a URL with a browser when the URL has double quotes:

Solve quotes within quotes with URL encoding:

Encode the inner quote marks with url encoding: `"` becomes `%22`

[Url encoding](https://www.bing.com/search?&q=URL+Encode). My installation of Opera does not have launcher.exe

```
C:\...\Opera\launcher.exe "https://www.google.de/search?hl=en&q=%22hello+world%22"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\opera.exe" "https://www.google.de/search?hl=en&q=%22hello+world%22"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using replacing:

```bat
?search="hello+world"  -->  ".../search?q=\"hello+world\""
or.. 
?search="hello+world"  -->  .../search?q=\"hello+world\"
```

```bat
\"quotation marks with escaping\" 

"%userprofile%\appdata\Local\Programs\Opera\launcher.exe"  https://www.google.de/search?q=\"hello+world\"
```

- Or

```bat
enclosing \"quotation marks with escaping\"
"%userprofile%\appdata\Local\Programs\Opera\launcher.exe"  "https://www.google.de/search?q=\"hello+world\""
```